# How to get more diagnostic output on a "no module named xyz" error?

Tags: python, django

I have, in a local directory, a django project that works
fine when I run it from a local django server, as in

```
python manage.py runserver.py 8000
```

But if I clone the local git repository where this project
lives (and which is up-to-date), like this:

```
git clone my_django_project my_django_project_clone
```

and I try the same command above from the clone's directory, the
server fails *immediately*:

```
Error: No module named xyz
```

The server produces *no other output at all*, even when I run it
with the `-v 3` flag.

Is there any way to get more diagnostic information on why
this (supposedly) identical clone of a working django site is
failing?

Comment: Does running [`manage.py check`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#check-appname-appname) provide better output? I hate how `manage.py` swallows errors. All I can say is it's probably in `models.py` in some app, or maybe your views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem

1. Start interactive Python prompt

   ```
    python -vvv   # -vvv notes to print out import trace information
   ```
2. Type

   ```
    import xyz
   ```

If this works it means the module is valid Python installation. If it doesn't work with Django then it is a probably an issue with circular imports and problem with Django initialization code itself. Django does a lot of behind the scenes magic when it reads `settings.py` file, scans all Django applications and so on, so circular import is often the case why Python cannot load the module. Also this could be a case that Django swallows the original `ImportError` exception and does not print the nested exception what actually when wrong when initializating Django. In this case, manually typing `import xyz` should show you the real error.

3. If the module loading fails then the next thing is to type

   ```
   import sys
   for p in sys.path: print(p)  # print p for Python 2.x
   ```

This will show all directories where Python pulls in modules. Your module isn't probably in any of these directories so you need to make sure

A) You append your own modules to Python sys.path list or use [PYTHONPATH](http://users-cs.au.dk/chili/PBI/pythonpath.html) environment variable correctly to load your own packages. Settings up path may depend on Django version, Python version and how Django is run. For example the current working directory where you run `manage.py` command may or may not be included. If the module is in the current folder you can try this:

```
   PYTHONPATH=. python manage.py runserver
```

B) You install your third party packages properly. [The proper way to install third party Python packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments) is using `pip` tool with `virtualenv` isolated Python environment for your development project. If you install Python packages to system-wide Python installation (`/usr/lib/python` on UNIX), especially using `sudo pip`, the result is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the dependencies. A common thing is to store dependencies inside requirements.txt and run "pip install -r requirements.txt" when you clone a project. To push dependencies into requirements.txt you use "pip freeze > requirements.txt". So, if you project uses PIL or six or whatever it will be added to that file and then you can pip install them with a single command. I hope I haven't missed your point.