# Error importing h5py

Tags: python, h5py

I've been trying to import h5py to read this type of file.

Here is my code:

```
import h5py

file_1 = h5py.File("Out_fragment.h5py")

print file_1
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./week11.py", line 17, in <module>
    import h5py
ImportError: No module named h5py
```

I also used pip install h5py to get this module and am not sure why it did not seem install properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Please read how to install Python packages properly https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/29792831/315168

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu. You can try the following three commands:

1. `sudo pip install cython`
2. `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`
3. `sudo pip install h5py`

source: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3426

Answer (score 0):

For windows you just need to install it normally using easy install feature:

```
pip install h5py
```

you can visit their website from here: [H5py](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/)