# ImportError: No module named 'h5py.tests'

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

Unable to `import h5py`.

Have tried `pip uninstall h5py` and `pip install h5py`.

```
----> 7 import h5py
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import pandas as pd

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py in <module>()
     60 from .version import version as __version__
     61 
---> 62 from .tests import run_tests
     63 
     64 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:

ImportError: No module named 'h5py.tests'
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831052/error-importing-h5py

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python3 or above you need to run

```
pip3 install h5py
```