# No module named osgeo.ogr

Tags: python, virtualenv, gdal

I need to import `osgeo.ogr` module to `virtualenv` python program.

Global python has this module:

```
user@ubuntu:~/$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import osgeo
>>>
```

But into virtualenv (without --no-site-packages):

```
user@ubuntu:~$ temp/bin/python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import osgeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named osgeo
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29792831/315168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved in this way:

```
(VIRTUAL_ENV)user@ubuntu:~$ pip install --no-install GDAL==1.11.2
```

1.11.2 because my version GDAL is 1.11.2:

```
(VIRTUAL_ENV)user@ubuntu:~$ gdal-config --version
1.11.2
```

next:

```
(VIRTUAL_ENV)user@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/VIRTUAL_ENV/build/GDAL/
(VIRTUAL_ENV)user@ubuntu:~/.virtualenvs/VIRTUAL_ENV/build/GDAL$ python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal/
(VIRTUAL_ENV)user@ubuntu:~/.virtualenvs/bamap/build/GDAL$ pip install --no-download GDAL
```

`--include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal/` for me is correct. GDAL was installed with Quantum GIS in my system. If you will build GDAL manually paths may be others. Full version:

```
python setup.py build_ext --gdal-config=/YOUR_PATH/bin/gdal-config --library-dirs=/YOUR_PATH/gdal/VERSION_GDAL/lib --libraries=gdal --include-dirs=/YOUR_PATH/gdal/VERSION_GDAL/include
```

Details may find [here](http://tylerickson.blogspot.ru/2011/09/installing-gdal-in-python-virtual.html).

Comment: can you update the `pip install --no-install` option, as it no more exists? This resource may help other people who got stuck: https://gist.github.com/cspanring/5680334

Answer (score 9):

Able to solve with this one

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==`gdal-config --version`
```

Answer (score 1):

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && sudo apt-get update`
>
> if you have facing the issue " Cannot import name '_gi' ":
>   [visit this link to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389831/cannot-import-name-gi)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version) --global-option=build_ext --global- 
option="-I/usr/include/gdal"
```