# Cannot import name '_gi'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pi

I'm trying to add a repository to ppa with the `add-apt-repository` commands but the `_gi` module from Python is not found.

I did this command : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:s-mankowski/ppa-kf5`

Here is the traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

I'm on Ubuntu with Python3.7, I tried many solutions like but it doesn't work :

```
$ cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
$ sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

$ cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi
$ sudo ln -s _gi.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I can't use the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:s-mankowski/ppa-kf5` command but running a Python file with `python3 {file}` works.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I have a number of GTK projects running on Python3.6 and I will change each to a more recent Python, something 3,7 or after. If I use any of these fixes on the first project will they break the other projects that are still on 3,6? Or will I have to make sure that 3.6 remains on every system where I want to run the project?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ubuntu does not like to switch its default interpreter away from python 3.7.

So switch it back to 3.6 by using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

After that try to install the `gi` package:

```
sudo apt install python3-gi
```

Comment: What is your python interpreter? I.e. when you type `python3`, which version is displayed?
And can you type `import gi` in your python3 interpreter?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.5 with GCC 8.3, the Traceback is there when I write `import gi`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? You could also try to: `python3 -m pip install gi` after uninstalling `python3-gi`

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and the command `python3 -m pip install gi` doesn't works, It is returning `No matching distribution found for gi`

Comment: Ubuntu does not really like to use another python interpreter for its system. You could try to switch back to python3.6 `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and retry the installation.

Comment: It worked but it's hardly badly done, thanks M. Spiller

Comment: so basically the only solution is to use 3.6?

Comment: A hacky fix to get it working with python3.7 `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Answer (score 57):

Thanks to [a comment by Wilhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389831/cannot-import-name-gi/62672285#comment108816661_59389914), I found that the solution is:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

This worked for me with Python 3.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you provide a short explanation of how this fixes the issue?

Comment: This worked for me also.  It's creating a symlink to the existing 3.6 library that is named as if it was a 3.7 library.  My assumption is that that python 3.7 fails to load the 3.6 library and this fixes that in a similar way to https://askubuntu.com/a/1207369

Comment: This works for me too. I installed python 3.7 and 3.8 and had the same problem. Replacing `{36m,37m}` with `{35m,37m,38}` creates the two symlinks for `37m` and `38`. This allows me to open the `gnome-terminal` again.

Comment: Also `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` worked when switching from py 3.5 to py 3.8

Comment: had to do it for both gi/_gi.cpython gi/_gi_cairo.cpython and cairo/_cairo.cpython

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me after trying this command post solution one.

Comment: Have in mind that you should be in the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/` directory when using the command so the link is created there.

Answer (score 14):

This is an old issue, but if someone needs a quick solution , that doesn't imply changing the default Python versions anywhere, just:

```
sudo python3.6 /usr/bin/apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
```

Comment: Can you explain what this thing does?

Comment: @fsevenm it simply uses the python3.6 binary to run the apt-add-repository , solving the library's conflict existing on `python3.7+` .  For me the issue was only appearing while adding the repo. So i didn't want to change between default versions of python. But you could  change it back to an older version like the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: This solution worked for me on ubuntu 18.04 and I upgraded my python to 3.7 a while back. The other suggestions of "ln -s" don't make sense as they didn't even provide a target. Usage: ln -s source target.

Comment: Best solution if you just want to run `apt-add-repository`. Leaves no side-effect.

Answer (score 8):

These 2 steps may help you

```
$ cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi
$ sudo ln -s _gi.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'd like to know why would this happen and how to avoid it? I found this name error happened in many scene.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps to solve the issue.

(1)    ls -al /usr/bin | grep python

(2)    sudo gedit /usr/bin/add-apt-repository

Then change the !/usr/bin/python3 to

```
!/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Answer (score 3):

when you check `sudo apt install python3-gi` it says "it's already installed to newest version"
but your import gi is not working, so you should check its directory

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi
```

and you will see which version of python you are using in my case: "_gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" that is 38 => python3.8
so you should check `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` to see if there is python3.8 to point or not, if not simply do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

and make sure your python3 is pointing to python3.8
you can check it by: `ls -l /etc/alternatives/python3`
Done.