# Docker Installation: ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am getting following error while Adding the Docker repository to APT sources for installing docker in ubuntu 18.04 using this tutorial [install docker ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Tried to change the python version from 3.7 to 3.6 with no luck.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot import name '\_gi'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389831/cannot-import-name-gi)

Comment: Hey, Had tried that. Din;t work for me

Comment: Used answer from one of the comments . Worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked using this command in python3.7 [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389831/cannot-import-name-gi)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```