# python soaplib ImportError: No module named core.service

Tags: python, python-2.7, soaplib

I'm developing python application and using soaplib for use in .net 
but when I run the code , I ran into this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soap.py", line 2, in <module>
    from soaplib.core.service import rpc, DefinitionBase
ImportError: No module named core.serviceImportError: No module named core.service
```

How do I solved this?

Comment: Here are some generic guidelines how to debug ImportErrors http://stackoverflow.com/a/29792831/315168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem like this 
download tar.gz soaplib file from this address 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/soaplib/2.0.0-beta2
and install it with this command 
`sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Bear in mind it looks like `soaplib` is not in active development. The new name is [spyne](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyne). The version you have installed is a beta and it wouldn't be a good idea to use it in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install following version

```
sudo pip install soaplib==2.0.0-beta2
sudo pip install suds==0.4
```

Comment: Why would you suggest using sudo?

Comment: its your wish,if you are  in  root no need to use sudo otherwise it will show permission denied error

Comment: It probably won't. It depends how your system is set up and whether you want to install globally, locally or to a virtual environment. I would suggest making examples default to not requiring root.