# Import error: No module named P4API

Tags: python, perforce

I tried downloading the Perforce for python API (Platform independent)version from [here](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/apis) and tried executing a simple connect() script:

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "111"
p4.user = "xxx"
p4.client = "yyy"
p4.connect()
```

I have this script and p4.py and the remaining dist stuff(c++ files) in the same folder. But I get this error:

```
Importerror: No module named P4API.
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783849/how-to-get-more-diagnostic-output-on-a-no-module-named-xyz-error? for general guidelines how to troubleshoot Python import issues

Comment: I tried everything suggested in those answers. Yet the error remains

Comment: The linked answer is not a solution, but a way to diagnose the problem. Can you add sample output from the commands and your folders to the question? Which Python interpreter you use, how did you install the package, etc.

Comment: Oh Yeah I just tried that and found out. Check my answer below. It was the interpreter. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Good job you figured it out :)

Answer (score 4):

So I found out what was messing things up. My Python 2.7 is 32 bit and the Perforce build which I downloaded (and which is put up on their site) is 64 bit. Here's the link you have to follow if you have a 32 bit Python.

[This link has the 32 bit python distribution of P4P](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/utils/python/bin/p4python-2014.1.807760.win32-py2.7.exe?v=1)

To check whether you have a 32 bit or 64 bit Python just go to your command line and start the python shell(type python). The first line contains this information.

Comment: More recent link https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-proxy-server-p4p

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got that error because I had forgotten to install the module after building. I was missing the following command

```
sudo python3 setup.py install --apidir <Perforce C++ API absolute path>
```

[I followed this instructions](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4pythonnotes.txt)