# Python: How to import zip from a different directory

Tags: python, azure, import, webjob

I am deploying some python scripts as Azure Web Jobs and ran into an issue with importing some shared modules (in the form of zip files). Everything works fine if I copy the zip files to the same directory as the script file. But if I move the zip files to a different directory, things stop working.

Now for the specifics.

1) This works

Directory structure:

```
App_data
  jobs
    continuous
      firstjob
        azure.zip
        job1.py
      secondjob
        azure.zip
        job2.py
```

In job1.py (and job2.py), I add the following code:

```
  sys.path.insert(0, 'azure.zip')
  from azure.storage.blob import *
```

1) This does NOT work

Directory structure:

```
App_data
  pylib
    azure.zip
  jobs
    continuous
      firstjob
        job1.py
      secondjob
        job2.py
```

In job1.py (and job2.py), I add the following code:
  # Azure places the scripts one level lower than it appears in the solution, hence the extra '..'!

```
  lib_path = os.path.realpath('..\..\..\pylib')
  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(lib_path, 'azure.zip'))
  # I verified by printing sys.path that the correct path is added for azure.zip
  from azure.storage.blob import *
```

This gives an import error. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783849/how-to-get-more-diagnostic-output-on-a-no-module-named-xyz-error

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code above in my local using pycharm. The second code can also work well. I am using python3.5.0. I am not sure why the error appears. Maybe the issue of python version in Azure. Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find out the reason of this issue for the second job via run the code snippet below.

```
import os
real_path = os.path.realpath('.')
print real_path
```

The result of variable `real_path` of the current webjob path is `D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\second\<a generated name like vjvunhav.obn>\`.

> **Note**
>
> Please see [the section `Logging` of Wiki-Doc `Web Jobs`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#logging) to know the path of `WebJobs - Console.Out and Console.Error`.

So you can try to directly use the absolute path `/Home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/pylib/azure.zip` in the code below.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/pylib/azure.zip')
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

When the azure webjob is executed, the content of the directory is copied in a temp subdirectory of your website "data" folder (at the root /data).

If you put the zip file in the same folder than your Python script, it will be copied too. If not, you need to use the absolute path "/site/wwwroot/mysite/App_data/pylib/"

That should work !